# How to open MYSQL port 8889 / 3306 at macOS Mojave?

Tags: mysql, macos, port

I need to connect 2 computers windows and mac. And want to write from one to another. I opened port 3306 at windows and I am able to write to DB at windows. But my MAC don't want to allow write to the DB from Windows. I turned off firewall but it doesn't help, **Could you tell me how to open MYSQL port 8889 at macOS Mojave?**

//EDIT:

**SOLVED**

If you want open port 3306 run this command at terminal. It will run listener from netcat at port 3306

`nc -l 3306`

Comment: Like you said that you have already turned OFF the firewall, then it should work. Please try to telnet from windows to check if the port is open on mac?

Comment: I already solved it. I tried several ways, nothing work. Than I changed MAMP server ports from 8889 to 3306. And run listener in terminal at port 3306. It helped me.

`nc -l 3306`

Comment: @Guminator if you've solved it, please post your solution as an answer to your own question (and remove the edit).